# Azure Cloud Shell in Windows Terminal App

Tags: azure-cli

Once Azure Cloud Drive shell of Windows Terminal, it seems to default to PowerShell.
I can switch to Bash by typing Bash.
But once inside BASH shell can I switch to PowerShell again?  Typing PS or PowerShell doesn't seem to work.

Comment: does pulling down the menu that says Powershell in this image do it? https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-shell/media/features-powershell/exchangeonline.png

Answer (score 2):

I can see two ways to do this

1. You can type `exit` to get out of `bash` and into PS.

```
PS /home/roshan> bash

roshan@Azure:~$ exit
exit

PS /home/roshan>
```

2. Type `pwsh` to open a new PS

```
PS /home/roshan> bash
roshan@Azure:~$ pwsh

PowerShell 7.0.0
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

https://aka.ms/powershell
Type 'help' to get help.


MOTD: To Connect and Manage Exchange Online: Connect-EXOPSSession

VERBOSE: Authenticating to Azure ...
WARNING: Azure Authentication failed.
Loading personal and system profiles took 63433ms.

PS /home/roshan>
```